# Can't show a Menu Item that's been hidden in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` on a later moment

Tags: actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I want to create a menu item and show it in a later moment, when an event occurs.. however, when I fire `menuItemDone.setVisible(true);` later on the code the menu item doesn't show. It stays hidden. Any idea of how I can create a hidden menu item and activate when an event occurs? The Menu is inflated in an activity and a what the fragment does:

```
        @Override
        public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            menuItemDone = menu.findItem(R.id.pi_menu_done);
            if(some condition){
              menuItemDone.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use `invalidateOptionMenu()` when u want to change.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me..

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    Menu m_menu = menu;
    m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+1, 0, "one");
    m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+2, 0, "two");
    m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+3, 0, "three");
    m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+4, 0, "four");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
     Menu m_menu = menu;

     if(bTested)
     {
         m_menu.findItem(Menu.FIRST+1).setVisible(false);
         m_menu.findItem(Menu.FIRST+2).setVisible(true);
     }
     else
     {
         m_menu.findItem(Menu.FIRST+1).setVisible(true);
         m_menu.findItem(Menu.FIRST+2).setVisible(false);
     }

     if(bConnected)
     {
         m_menu.findItem(Menu.FIRST+3).setVisible(false);
         m_menu.findItem(Menu.FIRST+4).setVisible(true);
     }
     else
     {
         m_menu.findItem(Menu.FIRST+3).setVisible(true);
         m_menu.findItem(Menu.FIRST+4).setVisible(false);
     }

     return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```